# Ionic App Icon not appearing in task / applications view

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I just got into ionic and I made my first app.
 I would like to know how to change the icon that is presented here:

[image]

I did already change the normal icon that is displayed, like so :

[image]
I have checked the docs and also have been scouring the whole internet to figure out how to fix this.

Comment: Try to install in another device. may be default icon is cached on your device. Uninstall the app then you may have to look for your app data and clear it then install the app.

Comment: is the first photo from notification tray? if yes, you have t create a notification icons for your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the command

> ionic cordova res

didn't replace the small icons.